# input value from website into a cell iterating to the next row

Tags: python, excel, loops, row

Building script for work that parses through a list of IPs and checks them against a website. If the website says its malicious, it grabs the IP from the website and then its SUPPOSED to input into the first cell of a spreadsheet, then if it finds another IP, puts it in the next rows cell, but all it's doing is just overwriting the previous IP.

```py
if 'was found in our database!' in elem[0].text:
    elem = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'text-primary')
    workbook = Workbook('hello.xlsx')
    sheet = workbook.active
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, min_col=1):
        for cell in row:
            cell.value = cell.append([elem.text])

    workbook.save('hello.xlsx')
```

Comment: For my understanding, the loop here would put an IP into the first cell of the spreadsheet. However, when the code tries to put another IP, this loop is executed again, and the first cell is filled with the new IP.